Proof of Strong Universality of a Hash Function
I read about a Strongly universal hash function from 64-bit keys to 32 bits, in this paper.
It uses the following function:
$h(x) = ((a_1 + x) \cdot (a_2 +  (x \gg 32)) + b) \gg (64 - \ell)$
Where $a_1$, $a_2$, $b$ are chosen at random and you want to hash into the range $\{0,...,2^{\ell}-1\}$.
I want to prove that this hash function is strongly universal but I have been struggling to do so. The definition of a strongly universal hash function is:
$\forall h \in H, \ \operatorname{Pr}[h(x)=a \wedge h(y)=b] 
 \leq \frac{1}{m^2}$ .
